# /bin/sh: ntpq: command not found

Tags: bash, shell, process, cron, ntp

I've got this strange behaviour [Empty string parsing ntpq command result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46583758/2553194), but let me resume and refocus the problem:

I'm executing a java program launched using a shell script that goes like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=.:$PATH

java -jar myJar.jar &
```

Inside my java code I execute this piped command

```
ntpq -c peers | awk ' $0 ~ /^\*/ {print $9}'
```

in order to obtain the offset of the NTP synchronized server.

To execute a piped command inside a java program, I've to use the above mentioned line as an argument of /bin/sh. **I execute /bin/sh not the piped command directly.**

This is the equivalent that you can launch in a console [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46583758/2553194)

```
/bin/sh -c 'ntpq -c peers | awk '"'"' $0 ~ /^\*/ {print $9}'"'"''
```

Example output from `ntpq`

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*172.30.100.1    172.22.204.171   4 u  207 1024  377    1.490   53.388  49.372
```

Parsing it with `awk`, I obtain

```
53.388
```

Usually it goes well, but sometimes for reasons unknown [This is my question] my program stops working fine. It returns nothing when the execution of the piped command from the console returns a number.

Recovering the err from the executed process created by java, I've obtained this text

> /bin/sh: ntpq: command not found

So, sometimes I can execute [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46583758/2553194) from a java program and sometimes I can't. Something is happening in the SO behind the scene. Can someone enlighten me, please?

Comment: Have you tried to pass the full path to the `ntpq` binary? Does this cause issues?

Comment: @val0x00ff You mean executing `/bin/sh -c '/usr/sbin/ntpq -c peers | awk '"'"' $0 ~ /^\*/ {print $9}'"'"''` from my java code? I've just tried and it works. But my original solution works too until it doesn't. I don't know how to force the anomalous situation. How can I proof that yours is better? :-(

Comment: This could be caused by `ntpq` not always return the expected result. For example, I just ran `ntpq -c peers` and I get things like `*46.243.26.34 (4 .GPS.            1 u   15   64    3   22.912   -1.441   4.577
` As you can see `column 9` isn't the offset anymore.  Also are you exporting JAVA as well?

Comment: @val0x00ff So you have a different SO or a different ntpq implementation, haven´t you? Anyway, it doesn`t explain why sometimes my SO found ntpq command and sometimes doesn't. Thanx for your comments :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I originally posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46583758/empty-string-parsing-ntpq-command-result) in StackOverflow, thinking that the problem may be related with the java programming but it wasn't.

Finally we found what was happening.

My java program is launched with a shell script. When we execute the script manually, `ntpq` command is found and invoked successfully. The problem arises when the software is fully deployed. In the final environment we've got a `cron` scheduled demon that keeps our program alive but `PATH` established by `cron` is different from the `PATH` that our profile has got assigned.

`PATH` used by cron:

```
.:/usr/bin:/bin
```

`PATH` that we got login for launching the script manually:

```
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:/local/users/nor:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/lib:.
```

Usually `ntpq` is in

```
/usr/sbin/ntpq
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths) you can find a better description of the problem and various solutions.